# Fileprovider raises issue

Tags: android-studio

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/aaaw.mp3";
                File f = new File(path);
                getUriForFile(getContext(), "haydo.kufurbaz.kfrbazhaydosesleri", f);
                Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), "haydo.kufurbaz.kfrbazhaydosesleri.fileprovider", f);

                Intent myınIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                myınIntent.setType("audio/*");
                String sharebody = "Your body here";
                myınIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myınIntent, "Share using"));
                myınIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                myınIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                myınIntent.setData(contentUri);
            return true;
```

It raises error like that:

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Help me please.